# SparkleXRM empty GUID after SOAP request create

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I have a problem with FetchXML in SparkleXML. When I want to add GUID filter in condition clause in FetchXML I get empty string value in SOAP request

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' returntotalrecordcount='true' no-lock='true' distinct='false'>
                              <entity name='ic_orderline'>
                                <attribute name='ic_orderlineid' />
                                <attribute name='ic_quantity' />
                                <attribute name='ic_product' />
                                <filter type='and'>
                                  <condition attribute='ic_order' operator='eq' value=''/>
                                </filter>
                              </entity>
                            </fetch>";
```

Fetch looks like one above in SOAP request. Anyone had problem like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I passed GUID in curly brackets format (eg.`"{F2D136B5-3439-E611-80E9-5065F38A3951}"`), but you need to pass GUID without brackets (`"F2D136B5-3439-E611-80E9-5065F38A3951"`) because there is some regex in JavaScript that escapes curly brackets and it's contents in FetchXML.